# Finite and Infinite Dimentional Spaces.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is the space $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$ finite or infinite dimentional?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: @Arpit Kansal....infinite dimentional

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: I remembered the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that the set $\{\sin(nx): n \in \mathbb N\}$ is linear independent in $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$.

Conclusion ?

Comment: It is not so clear for me how to prove the linear independence of an infinite set?.... could u explain for me?

Comment: You have to show that $N \in \mathbb N$, $t_1,...,t_N$ scalars and $0=t_1 \sin(x)+t_2 \sin (2x) +....+t_N \sin(Nx)$ imply $t_1= ...=t_N=0$.

Comment: could you recommend a book for me for linear independence of infinite sets ?